# Add dynamic view to specific RecyclerView.Adapter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-databinding

I'm currently testing my code for situations where a `RecyclerView.Adapter` needs additional information to be displayed in it. Using the code below which is inside `onBindViewHolder`, I was able to make this work.

```
TableRow row = new TableRow(mCtx);
row.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
row.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

TextView lbl = new TextView(mCtx);
lbl.setText("Desc1");

TextView lbl2 = new TextView(mCtx);
lbl2.setText("54.77");

row.addView(lbl);
row.addView(lbl2);

holder.binding.tblTicketItemDetails.addView(row);
```

That code is always called inside `OnBindViewHolder` to simulate that each item have additional info in them. If I keep creating an item by pressing a `Button`, the additional info increases for each item.

How do I target the specific adapter's layout while using `DataBinding`?

This is the layout that I am using for `RecyclerView.Adapter`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="ticket_item"
            type="com.example.com.TicketItem" />
    </data>

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow6"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:weightSum="2"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lblTicketItemName"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:text="@{ticket_item.description}"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                tools:text="Test Text" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lblTicketItemPrice"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="end"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:text="@{ticket_item.price}"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                tools:text="Test Text" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/tblTicketItemDetails"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tableRow6">

        </TableLayout>

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

I want to add a `TableRow` with 2 `TextView`s in `tblTicketItemDetails` if needed. What is the best way to do this? If I can't do it while using `DataBinding`, then I would switch to the old way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually add dynamic views like this using Databinding:

```
@BindingAdapter({"addDynamicView", "position"})
public static void addDynamicView(TableLayout layout, TicketItem item, int position) {
   // LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(layout.getContext()); // if you need layout inflater
    for (int i = 0; i <= position; i++) { // loop to whatever condition you have
        TextView lbl = new TextView(layout.getContext());
        lbl.setText("Desc1");
        layout.addView(lbl);
    }
}
```

Modify TableLayout in xml,

```
 <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/tblTicketItemDetails"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tableRow6"
            app:addDynamicView = "@{ticket_item}"
            app:position = "@{position}">
```

Declare a new variable in xml,

```
<variable
            name="position"
            type="int" />
```

Send position from Java to xml

```
holder.binding.setVariable(BR.position, position);
```

or

```
holder.binding.setPosition(position);
```

Comment: Where can I call `addDynamicView`? Can I call it on a `Button` `onClick`?

Comment: you dont need to call that manually. it will be called automatically by the line in xml ` app:addDynamicView = "@{ticket_item}" ` Also I have added code to have changes with position. If you want I can write the full xml and java. Let me know.

Comment: @rminaj upvote the answer if helped and accept if worked.

Comment: Where do I get BR.position?

Comment: It will auto generate once you declare the position variable in xml.

Comment: Should my code look like `holder.binding.setVariable(holder.binding.getPosition(), position);`?

Comment: No. BR is generated automatically. Same as R. The import is yourpackagename.BR same as yourpackagename.R It’s auto generated in compile time like R.

Comment: Oh. I don't know that.

Comment: How do you set `variable ticket_item` from java to xml? Lets move to chat.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195729/discussion-between-derek-and-rminaj).